# Fill out hierarchical table

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have the following table:

```
B        categoryA
C           cateogoryB
D               categoryC  descC1
E                   item1  desc1
E                   item2  desc3
E                   item3  desc4
E                   item4  desc5
E                   item5  desc6
```

It is a tab-delimited table, between `item` and `desc` are two blank chars.

Now I want to fill out this table automatically in bash, so that each tab below a category is replaced with the value until there is a new category.

This is my desired output:

```
E        categoryA  cateogoryB  categoryC  descC2   item1  desc1
E        categoryA  cateogoryB  categoryC  descC3   item2  desc3
E        categoryA  cateogoryB  categoryC  descC4   item3  desc4
E        categoryA  cateogoryB  categoryC  descC5   item4  desc5
E        categoryA  cateogoryB  categoryC  descC6   item5  desc6
```

How can I accomplish this using bash?

I started to modify the table to be fully tab separated (`sed 's/^B /B\t/g' ko00002_mod.keg | sed 's/^C    /C\t\t/g' | sed 's/^D      /D\t\t\t/g' | sed 's/^E        /E\t\t\t\t/g'`, but I don't know a command that would fill out the table tbh.

Comment: Could you please post the effort which you have put in order to solve this question with CODE TAGS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ /[^[:space:]]/) {
            def[i] = ($i ~ /[^[:space:]]/ ? $i : def[i])
        }
        else {
            $i = def[i]
        }
    }
}
/^E/ {
    split($(NF-1),tmp," ")
    sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",tmp[2])
    $(NF-1) = tmp[1] "  " tmp[2] (++cnt) + 1
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
E       categoryA       cateogoryB      categoryC  descC2       item1  desc1
E       categoryA       cateogoryB      categoryC  descC3       item2  desc3
E       categoryA       cateogoryB      categoryC  descC4       item3  desc4
E       categoryA       cateogoryB      categoryC  descC5       item4  desc5
E       categoryA       cateogoryB      categoryC  descC6       item5  desc6
```

Comment: I am always amazed what awk is capable of. Thanks!